# (error)ZEncoding.pas(1054): Undeclared identifier: 'ZsetString' on delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

What's wrong with this message? Can anyone help me with this error?
 (error)ZEncoding.pas(1054): Undeclared identifier: 'ZsetString' on delphi 7

Comment: plz show code from this unit

Comment: it is a unit from zeos library, I suspect that the version you are using is not compatible with Delphi 7

Comment: @whosrdaddy AFAIK all versions of Zeos do work with Delphi 7. Ensure you got the latest 7.2 branch.

Comment: @Jayr ZSetString is defined in ZCompatibility.pas, which is defined in ZEncoding.pas. Ensure you got the latest Zeos revision, from the 7.2 branch.

Answer (score 1):

> What's wrong with this message?

Nothing is wrong with the message. It is telling you that line 1054 of the  `ZEncoding` unit refers to an identifier `ZsetString` that is not in scope.

This can mean many things, most commonly either of the following:

- Your code fails to use the unit which declared `ZsetString`.
- The use of the name `ZsetString` is a typo, and a different name was intended to be used.

To give a more detailed answer requires knowledge of the source code which only you have.